# Left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Symmetric group of order $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I’m having a hard time understanding cosets. I’m working through Gallians contemporary abstract and I don’t  even understand example one!

Let $G=S_3$ and $H=\{(1),(1\,3)\}$. Then it shows me the left cosets. I know $G$ is of order $6$ and $H$ is of order $2$, so there are definitely three cosets by Lagrange.

The coset def is for ANY $a \in G$, $Ha=\{ha\mid h \in H\}$

The preliminary step is:

$(1)H,\;(12)H,\;(13)H,\;(23)H$

If $S_3$ is $\{ 123,231,321,132,312,213\}$ why are our elements $a \in G$ above $12,13,23$. I think I get the identity one!

Further we have $1H=H$ and $13H=H$. I presume that's bc $1$ and $13$ are elements of $H$.

I totally do not get why $12H$ and $23H$ are considered and how they result in $132H$ and $123H$ respectively. I attempted the cyclic multiplication and for $12H$, I got $132H$ but with different steps and for $23H$, I got $321H$ which Ii suppose is the same as $123H$ per Gallian? But if those are identical why do we have two symmmetric members of $S_3$, $123$ and $321$, that it seems to me are not identical?

I’m spending dozens of hours trying to understand my first abstract course, which I suppose is normal, but nonetheless incredibly frustrating.

Thanks for your help

Marco

Comment: I suspect you're confusing the representation as a map – so when you write, say, $312$, it means that $\;1\mapsto3$, $2\mapsto 1$ and $3\mapsto2$, and the representation as a product of cycles – so the above map would be represented as the cycle $\;(1\,3\,2)$.

Comment: Ok i get that from the array notation, right? Help me see how that helps above lol. So when 1 maps to 3 and 3 maps to one, we close and record one. And then 3 to 2, so the total yield is 132?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with ‘we record one’. The identity?

Comment: Write down one as the first entry in the cycle?

Comment: Conventionally, one writes down the smallest unfixed number first.

Comment: Oh i think that answers a lot, we just choose to write one?

Comment: Just an example : the transposition which swaps $2$ and  $3$ (array notation: $\;\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\[-1ex]1&3&2\end{pmatrix}$) is written as a cycle $\;(2\,3)$. Usually, the cycle notation makes computations easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the elements of $S_3$ are permutations, so $(123)$ or $(12)$ means $1\to 2 \to 3 \to 1$ and $1 \to 2 \to 1$ respectively. What I understand from the question is that you have some difficulty in figuring out how to multiply the permutations, so first I will try to explain that and then we will get to cosets.

The group in consideration is $S_3 = \{ (1), (12),(23),(13),(123),(132)\}$ i.e. permutation on three elements namely $1,2$ and $3$.

Pick two elements from $G =S_3$ say $g_1 = (23), g_2 =(132)$, then $g_1 \cdot g_2 = (23)(132).$ So we need to figure out what this new pwermutation is? Since we know that $G$ is a group, this new element must also be in $G$ i.e. a permutation. So begin acting it on some element say $1$, then

$g_1\cdot g_2 [1] = (23)(132) [1] = (23)[2] = 3$, notice we first apply $(132)$ and then $(23)$. So $g_1 \cdot g_2$ sends $1$ to $3$. Similarly you can check that $2$ is fixed and $3$ goes to $1$. So $g_1 \cdot g_2$ is nothing but $(13) \in G = S_3$.

Now assuming you understood how to multiply permutations, we proceed with cosets.

As you mentioned, the cosets of a subgroup $H$ are either $Hg$ or $gH$ depending on which type of cosets you are looking for (right or left).

$\textbf{Remark}$: If $H$ is not a normal subgroup, these are different.

In our case we have $H = \{(1), (13)\}$, so to find all (left) cosets, we need to find $gH = \{gh\ |\ h \in H\}\ \forall\ g \in G$

These are:

$1)\ g =(1), gH = H$

$2)\ g =(12), gH = \{(12)(1), (12)(13)\} = \{(12),(132)\}$

$3)\ g =(23), gH = \{(23)(1), (23)(13)\} = \{(23),(123)\}$

$4)\ g =(13), gH = \{(13)(1), (13)(13)\} = \{(13), (1)\} = H$

$5)\ g =(123), gH = \{(123)(1), (123)(13)\} = \{(123), (12)\}$

$6)\ g =(132), gH = \{(132)(1), (132)(13)\} = \{(132),(23)\}$

Hence there are precisely $3$ distinct cosets.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

"The cosets are displayed as (1)H,(12)H,(13)H,(23)H".

This is definitely wrong. But you are right, there are 3 cosets, since the group has order 6 and the subgroup has order 2.

The cosets are

$H = (1)H = (13)H$,

$(123)H =\{(123)(12)\}$ and

$(132)H = \{(132),(23)\}$.

Comment: Ok, I mispoke. The preliminary step was (1)H, 12(H), (13)H, (23)H. Resulting in cosets H, 132(H) and (123)H. I don’t understand the preliminary step (Why were those values for a in G chosen)  or the cyclic multiplication (if that is indeed what is happening) that gets us to the final coset results.